# rsync --ignore-times parameter not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

I want to implement a comprehensive backup script based on `rsync`, so I'm just experimenting now to decide the correct parameters based on my requirement. Basically, I want that any changed file should be copied from source to destination, regardless of its modification time (ie. whether or not source file is older/newer than destination file, it should be copied if the contents differ). However, it isn't working:

```
../src/test.txt
../dst/test.txt
```

Above is the folder structure. When I first ran the below command for first time, it copied the `test.txt` from src to dst folder.

```
rsync -avh --ignore-times src/ dst/
```

Then, I modified the contents of src/test.txt and ran above command again, and this time too it copied the updated file to dst folder.

However, I then modified the test.txt in dst folder, and ran above command, but this time, it didn't work and didn't copy the file from src/ to dst/ folder. But considering [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124101/43159), it should have worked as I've added the `--ignore-times` parameter.

Is this a bug with Ubuntu, or am I doing something wrong? What parameter should I add so that the file will be always copied from source to destination when the contents differ (even when the destination file is newer)?

**edit**

I even tried adding the `--checksum` parameter to copy solely based on checksums and ignoring the timestamp altogether (as the man page says). But even that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, the `--archive` or `a` mode doesn't seem to work with the `--ignore-times` or `--checksum` parameters. However, the simple recursive copy mode (`--recursive` or `r`). So in my case, the following did the job perfectly:

```
rsync -vcr src/ dst/
```